# Why doesn't my code flip image horizontally?

Tags: java, for-loop, image-processing

```java
public void flipImageHorizontally(){
    this.redisplayImage();

    for(int x = 0; x < this.image.length; x++)
        for(int y = 0; y < this.image[0].length; y++){
            this.image[x][y] = this.image[x][this.image[0].length - 1 - y];
        }
}
```

The code runs but it doesn't perform the action intended. It is supposed to flip the image horizontally, but instead it only flips half of the image.

Comment: It would seem the `this.image[0].length` should be `this.image[x].length` but I'm guessing

Comment: @MadProgrammer Shouldn't make a difference. It's an image, so probably not a jagged array.

Comment: When you flip you will usually iterate only half and swap it with a temp var

Comment: Let's say the image is 4 pixels wide, then with your logic you put the value of pixel 4 into pixel one and at the end put the value of pixel 1 back into pixel 4.

Comment: Also, it looks like you redisplay the image before to flip it.

Answer (score 1):

You need to iterate up to the middle, and swap pixels that are on the left with pixels that are on the right. Otherwise you end up overwriting your changes.

```
public void flipImageHorizontally() {
    this.redisplayImage();

    for(int x = 0; x < this.image.length; x++) {
        for(int y = 0; y < this.image[x].length / 2; y++) {
            int pixel = this.image[x][y]; // assuming int
            
            this.image[x][y] = this.image[x][this.image[x].length - 1 - y];
            this.image[x][this.image[x].length - 1 - y] = pixel;
        }
    }
}
```

In this code

1. the `pixel` variable temporarily holds the value on the left;
2. the value on the left gets assigned the value on the right;
3. the value on the right gets the value that was originally on the left (i.e. whatever is in `pixel`).

---

**Notes:**

- I maintained your naming of `x` and `y`, even though it's counter-intuitive because it makes it look like you're performing a vertical flip instead of a horizontal one.
- I don't know the data type of the array; I assumed `int`, but it might be a `float` array, `Pixel` objects, or something else.
- I don't know what `this.redisplayImage();` is supposed to do, and whether it's in the right location.

Answer (score 1):

Let's say you have an image two pixels wide and one pixel high:

```
1 2
```

After the first iteration of your loop, the end pixel will be swapped to the beginning (`image[0][0] = image[0][2 - 1 - 0];`):

```
2 2
```

But now you lost the original value of `image[0][0]`! So when you do the swap `image[0][1] = image[0][2 - 1 - 1];`, you are copying the second half of the image back to itself.

The right answer is to use a buffer so you don't overwrite the swap:

```
for(int y = 0; y < this.image[0].length / 2; y++) {
    int buffer = this.image[x][y];
    this.image[x][y] = this.image[x][this.image[0].length - 1 - y];
    this.image[x][this.image[0].length - 1 - y] = buffer;
}
```

Integer truncation ensures that `this.image[0].length / 2` is an efficient bound. For even numbers, you iterate exactly the first half. For odd numbers, you iterate the first half, not including the middle pixel. That's a good thing, because the middle does not need to be swapped.